# invoke function by passing class name and namespace

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application to pass class name and namespace.I want to create an object of that class and call a function.
Am passing namespace as ServiceReference1 and class name as CrewServiceClient from text box as string.
I want to create object like below

```
ServiceReference1.CrewServiceClient cs = new ServiceReference1.CrewServiceClient();
```

and call functions using the object "cs" like `cs.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Activator.CreateInstance` already ?

```
Activator.CreateInstance("YourAssembly", "CrewServiceClient");
```

But you should define an interface to use the methods following the creation of the instance:

```
interface IServiceClient {
    string UserName;
}

class CrewServiceClient : IServiceClient {
    string UserName;
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
var instance = (IServiceClient)Activator.CreateInstance("YourAssembly", "CrewServiceClient");
var userName = instance.UserName;
```

Comment: "YourAssebly" means namespace?